# installed Android APK failed to launch if not compiled with that mobile (Physical Handset)

Tags: android, xamarin, mobile, android-install-apk

Given scenario.

I developed an app for business. Built using xamarin for jellybean and above. Changed Debug to Release to compile.

App  Settings:
Compile using Android version: use latest platform
Minimum Android Target: Android 4.1 Jellybean
Target Android version: use compile using sdk version

My problem is. After compilation to a specific mobile(lets say mobile1), my app will run perfectly on the it. But getting the signed APK on the bin-release folder and sending it to other phone (not yet compiled with and lets say this is mobile2), it always says app stopped at launch state. But recognizing the issue that it only stop if app is not yet compiled with the new phone. I tried to compile it with mobile2. Of course app will now work perfectly. And then I tried to uninstall the app (from mobile2) then install the apk I once compiled before with the mobile1 and it will now run. Why is it that app installed through won't launch unless app was compiled to that phone initially then it will now recognize the app from apk?

note: we intended not to send it to playstore. Just to pass the apk around.
What could be the issue with this? In compilation or coding or somewhere else?

Thanks in advance for the answer ! :)

Comment: what do you mean by "app compile with the mobile"? Do you mean you compile the app when your mobile is plugged in with your computer?

Comment: yes, with usb debugging enabled